# Quote Generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So today I am currently stuck on a problem I am trying to make a quote generator and when I do I have made sure there is no errors and when I click a button to add it to the results side it doesn't add ? can anyone see why this is happening?

https://jsfiddle.net/1x7kqdoc/1/

LIVE LINK : https://pricingtool-kstreakog.c9users.io/quote.php?

```
Please Help Me I need this !!!
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You post. So the javascript cannot do its work because the site is posted.
Use

```
Return false;
```

Or

```
("#id").on("click",function(event){
event.preventDefault()
}
```

To prevent the code from posting.
Also you could simply remove the form and replace the button type="submit" with type="".

Comment: where do I add this can you edit my js fiddle code plz :) Thanks <3

Comment: Add the return false at the end of every onclick handler

Comment: I have updated my code by putting return false; statements at end of each click still nothing works!